# UITableview cell delete. but deosn't reload cell

Tags: ios

[image]I want to refresh tagListTableView.

but it doesn't refresh.

When delete button on UITableview cell is tapped , object in coraData's date could be removed.

but, Deleting a cell in a table view is still exposed to the screen to blank.

I tried to [tagListTableView reloadData] on viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, .....more.

What am I missing??

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete; 
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
          commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
          forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        Voca_Tag *tag = (Voca_Tag *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tagListTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setSelected:NO animated:YES];

        [tag.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]]; //        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES]; 
        [tagListTableView reloadData];

        [pickedTags removeObject:tag];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![tag.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    } 
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
       canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        Voca_Tag *tag = (Voca_Tag *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tagListTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setSelected:NO animated:YES];

        [tag.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]]; //        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES]; 


        //********
        //REMOVE the object before reloading the table
        [pickedTags removeObject:tag];

        [tagListTableView reloadData];


        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![tag.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
```

You should remove object from your pickedTags before you reload the tableview, you were doing is after reload.

It might help you.